# what's your idea about "but although"

Tags: word-usage

once my student used the term **but although**,
I corrected her and asked her to use 'although' instead.
He insisted he had seen this word before.

I looked up and found we actually have this word.
Is it common? Can we use these two words together?
I found some examples from new york times and Guardian. Probably in Ame English?

Guardian: *But although I understand their arguments, I disagree.*

*But although the city was outraged, the murder went unsolved.*

Comment: Sounds awfully repetitious. Not to say you couldn't come up with an artificial sentence that forced the words next to each without actually working together: I am happy **but, although** it might not show, still grumpy.

Comment: As an experienced teacher, I know when to stop my students. I write their errors and mention their errors at the end. learn not to judge others. 
@casabel.

Comment: BTW...if you do not want to be judged based only on the quality of your post, I suggest that you complete the [Biography part of your  Profile page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/412606/user68857) ...it would help.

Answer (score 4):

*But* and *although* are entirely separate here, with different discourse functions: there is nothing wrong with using both of them.

*But* is connecting the sentence to the existing discourse, and expressing that this sentence is in some way differing or countering what has gone before.

*Although* is specifying some concession in the following sentence: this concession may or may not have been introduced to the discourse already.

> But although I understand their arguments, I disagree.

and

> Although I understand their arguments, I disagree.

have the same denotative meaning, but their role in the discourse is different: in the first, the speaker is giving notice that the sentence is somehow countering what has gone before, thye usual function of initial *but*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive response